# Is there PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST equivalent in Mac OS X?

Tags: c++, macos, mutex, robust

I'm using a `pthread_mutex_t` with `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED` on a shared memory to do synchronization between different processes.

The mutex maybe deadlocked if a process exits but leaves the mutex locked. There is a `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST` in POSIX standard. But it seems that Mac OS X does not support the `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST`.

Is there some kind of `mutex` on Mac OS X that can be used on a shared memory, and to be used to synchronize cross processes, and to be robust in case of a process die without unlock it?

Comment: Any ideas on how to bump this to Apple so that they implement this missing piece?

Answer (score 3):

The robust stuff appeared in a later iteration of POSIX threads (SUSv7), not part of the the standard supported by Mac OS X (which is SUSv2).

The Apple docs do not show a `pthread_mutexattr_setrobust` function (or its equivalent `get`) and they state that they're based on SUSv2, so that explains why you don't have it.

In terms of *fixing* the problem, you may consider something like the use of an `atexit` handler to free up whatever resources your exiting program may possess.

Or another possibility is to monitor the deadlock externally and clean up if a problem is found. For example, have a watchdog process with two threads along the following lines.

```
thread1:
    set variables gloabalNum and localNum to zero
    start thread2
    while true:
        sleep 60 seconds
        if globalNum == localNum:
            exit while
        end if
        localNum = globalNum
    end while

    kill all processes using mutex
    remove shared memory
    exit process

thread2:
    while true:
        lock mutex
        unlock mutex
        increment globalNum
        sleep 5 second
```

The watchdog effectively locks and unlocks the mutex every five seconds, incrementing a variable each time. If, for some reason, you get deadlock, `thread2` will halt and the variable will never be updated.

In the meantime, `thread1` is checking to make sure `thread2` is still running, by checking the variable against its local copy every minute. If it finds they're the same, it assumes `thread2` has halted due to deadlock and it then cleans up everything by shutting down all processes using the mutex and destroying it (by deleting the shared memory).

The watchdog can then exit and presumably whatever code you already have for starting the entire application will kick in at some point. Or you can have the watchdog process raise an alert of some sort before exiting, to ensure the problem gets looked at.

The idea behind a watchdog process is to make it as simple as possible, hopefully to the point where it's provably correct (or at least more so than your errant program).

There are no doubt many other possibilities depending on your overall architecture. I've just provided these few off the top of my head to give you something to think about.

Comment: Thank you. I'm wondering is there an equivalent function starts with `OSxxx` or `NSxxx` can do the task of mutex. And for 'atexit', I will make sure how about when Ctrl-C or crash.

Comment: @SswaterShi: don't know about that, sorry. I'm up with PThreads itself and threading in general but the _specifics_ of OS X is not one of my expertise areas.

Comment: `atexit()` doesn't work when the program gets killed.