# Building iotivity on mac

Tags: c++, macos, iot, scons, iotivity

According to the docs, Mac should be supported but when attempting to build iotivity some headers are used that I think are posix specific.

```
➜  iotivity git:(master) ✗ scons SYS_VERSION=10.12
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Checking for POSIX Thread Support...(cached) yes
HEAD is now at acf202a Fix stack corruption due to calling convention mismatch

*********************************** Info: *****************************************
* Using FORKED copy of libCoap located in:                                        *
* resource/csdk/connectivity/lib/libcoap-4.1.1                                    *
***********************************************************************************
Given Transport is ALL
Given OS is darwin
BUILD_SAMPLE is ON
MQ flag is OFF
Reading ca script ALL
Reading common folder script
Reading util folder script
Copied IoTivity version of config.h to /Users/zcourts/projects/iotivity/extlibs/mbedtls/mbedtls/include/mbedtls/config.h
Reading IP adapter script
Reading IP adapter script
Include path is ['../api', '/usr/local/include', '/Users/zcourts/projects/iotivity/deps/darwin/include', '/Users/zcourts/projects/iotivity/extlibs/tinycbor/tinycbor/src', '/Users/zcourts/projects/iotivity/resource/c_common', '/Users/zcourts/projects/iotivity/out/darwin/x86_64/release/resource/c_common/oic_malloc/include', '/Users/zcourts/projects/iotivity/out/darwin/x86_64/release/resource/c_common/oic_string/include', '/Users/zcourts/projects/iotivity/out/darwin/x86_64/release/resource/c_common/oic_time/include', '/Users/zcourts/projects/iotivity/out/darwin/x86_64/release/resource/c_common/ocatomic/include', '/Users/zcourts/projects/iotivity/out/darwin/x86_64/release/resource/c_common/ocrandom/include', '/Users/zcourts/projects/iotivity/out/darwin/x86_64/release/resource/c_common/octhread/include', '/Users/zcourts/projects/iotivity/out/darwin/x86_64/release/resource/c_common/oic_platform/include', '/Users/zcourts/projects/iotivity/out/darwin/x86_64/release/resource/c_common/octimer/include', '#/extlibs/mbedtls/mbedtls/include', '/Users/zcourts/projects/iotivity/out/darwin/x86_64/release/resource/csdk/logger/include', '#/resource/c_common', '#resource/csdk/connectivity/lib/libcoap-4.1.1/include', '../inc', '/Users/zcourts/projects/iotivity/resource/csdk/logger/include', '../common/inc', '../util/inc', '#resource/c_common/octhread/include/', '#resource/csdk/connectivity/common/inc/', '#resource/csdk/logger/include/', '#extlibs/mbedtls/mbedtls/include', '#/resource/c_common/octimer/include', '/Users/zcourts/projects/iotivity/resource/csdk/security/include', '../external/inc']
Files path is ['/Users/zcourts/projects/iotivity/resource/csdk/connectivity/common/src/uarraylist.c', '/Users/zcourts/projects/iotivity/resource/csdk/connectivity/common/src/ulinklist.c', '/Users/zcourts/projects/iotivity/resource/csdk/connectivity/common/src/uqueue.c', '/Users/zcourts/projects/iotivity/resource/csdk/connectivity/common/src/caremotehandler.c', '/Users/zcourts/projects/iotivity/resource/csdk/connectivity/common/src/cathreadpool_pthreads.c', '/Users/zcourts/projects/iotivity/resource/csdk/connectivity/util/src/cautilinterface.c', './adapter_util/caadapterutils.c', './adapter_util/cafragmentation.c', './adapter_util/ca_adapter_net_ssl.c', './cablockwisetransfer.c', './caconnectivitymanager.c', './cainterfacecontroller.c', './camessagehandler.c', './canetworkconfigurator.c', './caprotocolmessage.c', './caqueueingthread.c', './caretransmission.c', '/Users/zcourts/projects/iotivity/resource/csdk/connectivity/src/ip_adapter/caipadapter.c', '/Users/zcourts/projects/iotivity/resource/csdk/connectivity/src/ip_adapter/caipserver.c', '/Users/zcourts/projects/iotivity/resource/csdk/connectivity/src/ip_adapter/linux/caipnwmonitor.c']
*** Checking for installation of google unit test 1.7.0 ***
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: building associated VariantDir targets: out/darwin/x86_64/release
Compiling out/darwin/x86_64/release/resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.o
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:90:5: error: unknown type name 'pthread_mutex_t'; did you mean 'pthread_attr_t'?
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    pthread_attr_t
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk//usr/include/sys/_pthread/_pthread_attr_t.h:30:33: note: 'pthread_attr_t' declared here
typedef __darwin_pthread_attr_t pthread_attr_t;
                                ^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:103:5: error: unknown type name 'pthread_cond_t'; did you mean 'pthread_attr_t'?
    pthread_cond_t cond;
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    pthread_attr_t
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk//usr/include/sys/_pthread/_pthread_attr_t.h:30:33: note: 'pthread_attr_t' declared here
typedef __darwin_pthread_attr_t pthread_attr_t;
                                ^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:104:5: error: unknown type name 'pthread_condattr_t'; did you mean 'pthread_attr_t'?
    pthread_condattr_t condattr;
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    pthread_attr_t
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk//usr/include/sys/_pthread/_pthread_attr_t.h:30:33: note: 'pthread_attr_t' declared here
typedef __darwin_pthread_attr_t pthread_attr_t;
                                ^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:109:5: error: unknown type name 'pthread_t'
    pthread_t thread;
    ^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:128:22: warning: implicit declaration of function 'pthread_create' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        int result = pthread_create(&threadInfo->thread, NULL, start_routine, arg);
                     ^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:170:19: warning: implicit declaration of function 'pthread_join' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    int joinres = pthread_join(threadInfo->thread, NULL);
                  ^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:187:17: warning: implicit declaration of function 'pthread_mutex_init' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        int ret=pthread_mutex_init(&(mutexInfo->mutex), PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT);
                ^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:187:57: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT'
        int ret=pthread_mutex_init(&(mutexInfo->mutex), PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT);
                                                        ^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:215:19: warning: implicit declaration of function 'pthread_mutex_destroy' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        int ret = pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutexInfo->mutex);
                  ^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:239:19: warning: implicit declaration of function 'pthread_mutex_lock' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        int ret = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexInfo->mutex);
                  ^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:273:19: warning: implicit declaration of function 'pthread_mutex_unlock' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        int ret = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexInfo->mutex);
                  ^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:314:19: warning: implicit declaration of function 'pthread_condattr_init' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        int ret = pthread_condattr_init(&(eventInfo->condattr));
                  ^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:342:15: warning: implicit declaration of function 'pthread_cond_init' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        ret = pthread_cond_init(&(eventInfo->cond), &(eventInfo->condattr));
              ^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:350:13: warning: implicit declaration of function 'pthread_condattr_destroy' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
            pthread_condattr_destroy(&(eventInfo->condattr));
            ^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:367:19: warning: implicit declaration of function 'pthread_cond_destroy' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        int ret = pthread_cond_destroy(&(eventInfo->cond));
                  ^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:390:19: warning: implicit declaration of function 'pthread_cond_signal' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        int ret = pthread_cond_signal(&(eventInfo->cond));
                  ^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:407:19: warning: implicit declaration of function 'pthread_cond_broadcast' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        int ret = pthread_cond_broadcast(&(eventInfo->cond));
                  ^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:431:17: error: incomplete result type 'struct timespec' in function definition
struct timespec oc_get_current_time()
                ^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:431:8: note: forward declaration of 'struct timespec'
struct timespec oc_get_current_time()
       ^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:439:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'gettimeofday' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    ^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:440:21: error: variable has incomplete type 'struct timespec'
    struct timespec ts;
                    ^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:431:8: note: forward declaration of 'struct timespec'
struct timespec oc_get_current_time()
       ^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:448:5: error: unknown type name 'time_t'; did you mean 'size_t'?
    time_t secPart = microseconds/USECS_PER_SEC;
    ^~~~~~
    size_t
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk//usr/include/sys/_types/_size_t.h:30:32: note: 'size_t' declared here
typedef __darwin_size_t        size_t;
                               ^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:450:26: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct timespec'
    uint64_t totalNs = ts->tv_nsec + nsecPart;
                       ~~^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:431:8: note: forward declaration of 'struct timespec'
struct timespec oc_get_current_time()
       ^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:451:5: error: unknown type name 'time_t'; did you mean 'size_t'?
    time_t secOfNs = totalNs/NANOSECS_PER_SEC;
    ^~~~~~
    size_t
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk//usr/include/sys/_types/_size_t.h:30:32: note: 'size_t' declared here
typedef __darwin_size_t        size_t;
                               ^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:453:7: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct timespec'
    ts->tv_nsec = (totalNs)% NANOSECS_PER_SEC;
    ~~^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:431:8: note: forward declaration of 'struct timespec'
struct timespec oc_get_current_time()
       ^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:454:7: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct timespec'
    ts->tv_sec += secPart + secOfNs;
    ~~^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:431:8: note: forward declaration of 'struct timespec'
struct timespec oc_get_current_time()
       ^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:479:25: error: variable has incomplete type 'struct timespec'
        struct timespec abstime = { .tv_sec = 0 };
                        ^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:431:8: note: forward declaration of 'struct timespec'
struct timespec oc_get_current_time()
       ^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:495:19: warning: implicit declaration of function 'pthread_cond_timedwait' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
            ret = pthread_cond_timedwait(&(eventInfo->cond), &(mutexInfo->mutex), &abstime);
                  ^
resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.c:520:19: warning: implicit declaration of function 'pthread_cond_wait' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        int ret = pthread_cond_wait(&eventInfo->cond, &mutexInfo->mutex);
                  ^
15 warnings and 13 errors generated.
scons: *** [out/darwin/x86_64/release/resource/c_common/octhread/src/posix/octhread.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
➜  iotivity git:(master) ✗
```

I'm following the instructions at https://wiki.iotivity.org/macosx_build_instructions pointed to by https://wiki.iotivity.org/build_for_your_system

had a look but can't see any flags that'd enable mac support explicitly. Anyone know if this is actually supported and just been broken in recent commits? I building master checked out two days ago.

There is a `windows-port` branch but no mac named branches. `remotes/origin/1.3-rel` has the same issue.

Found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24947106/400048 which lead me to my assertion about the posix specific headers being used.

So, anyone know if this can be built on mac and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an "officially supported" platform or target at this point, I gather its health was better in the past.  Some people have had decent luck building for Mac, I have not. Changes to improve it will certainly considered, and there's an opening for a "Mac port maintainer" to make sure it doesn't rot again (and there's a github project which has added Mac buildability along with other build system reorgs - but I believe compared to iotivity that's rather out of date - however one could start picking fixes from there:  https://github.com/OpenOCF/iochibity)

Comment: I was pointed to that on their slack/irc chat. Testing with Ubuntu for now